# Change alias name for a field in Mongo Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When i execute the below query, i get proper response

```
db.getCollection('register').aggregate( [
  { $match: {"$or":[{"$and":[{"src":{"$in":["CR","FR"]}},{"status":{"$in":["Draft","InReview","Returned"]}},{kid:3940035}]}]} },
  { $group: {'_id':"$kid",'count':{'$sum':1}} }
] )
```

But I need to display kid as knowledge_id. So if the change from _id to knowledge_id the query returns an error as

The field '`knowledge_id`' must be an accumulator object' on server

Updated Query :

```
db.getCollection('register').aggregate( [
      { $match: {"$or":[{"$and":[{"src":{"$in":["CR","FR"]}},{"status":{"$in":["Draft","InReview","Returned"]}},{kid:3940035}]}]} },
      { $group: {'knowledge_id':"$kid",'count':{'$sum':1}} }
    ] )
```

Please help !!

Answer (score 1):

You can just add one more stage after the grouping ( grouping require always _id to be present ) :

```
 {$project:{"knowledge_id":"$_id", count:1}}
```

Comment: If i do a { $group: {'_id':"$kid",'count':{'$sum':1}} } it works. But if do a  { $group: {'knowledge_id':"$_id",'count':{'$sum':1}} }. Its not working